# adjust navbar and use it multiple times

Tags: filemaker

Hello I am currently working in Filemaker Pro 17 advanced. I have a navigation bar and I need to add a new button. When I add a new button in my nav bar it only shows in the tab where I added the extra button. So my question is how can I Add a button once and let it display in all my navbars?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there’s no native function to share objects between layouts. You can use global field repetitions to approximate shared objects but it has its limitations. What I tend to do is make sure my navigation is setup up correctly and then copy and paste it into other layouts.